# Как воспроизвести видеопоток

Tags: java, android, videoview

Отправляю изображение с вебкамеры в сеть по адресу http://192.168.1.199:8081. Что-то точно отправляется, потому что открыв адрес в браузере что-то скачивается. Использую кодер `h264`. Пытаюсь воспроизвести видео на телефоне с помощью `VideoView`. Получаю ошибку

```
 E/MediaPlayer: setDataSource: IOException! uri=http://192.168.1.199:8081
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://192.168.1.199:8081
```

Вот часть кода, где работаю с `VideoView`:

```
private String videoPath ="http://192.168.1.199:8081";
private static ProgressDialog progressDialog;
VideoView videoView ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    .....................................................

    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_stream);

    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Buffering video...", true);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(true);

    PlayVideo();
}

private void PlayVideo()
{
    try
    {
        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(MainActivity.this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

        Uri video = Uri.parse(videoPath );
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(video);
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()
        {

            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
            {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                videoView.start();
            }
        });


    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        System.out.println("Video Play Error :"+e.toString());
        finish();
    }

}
```

Comment: как понять " открыв адрес в браузере что-то скачивается"? У вас там картинка идет или нет?

Comment: картинка не идет, происходит бесконечная загрузка

Comment: Думается, прежде надо добиться чтобы видео хотя бы в браузере отображалось.

Comment: Для передачи видео использую следующий пример https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture/tree/master/webcam-capture-examples/webcam-capture-live-streaming

Comment: Если подскажите мне как это можно сделать по другому, и чтобы точно работало, то буду очень рад